# Does Root Boaster override system power management?

Tags: applications, root-access, power-options

In [Root Booster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ram.memory.booster.cpu.saver&hl=en) I have it set to Speed. Does Root Booster override the system's battery mode? For example when I change the battery mode from "balanced" to "power save", nothing seems to happen. Does Root Booster completely override this?

[image]

Comment: In general, these "booster" apps, or other apps which claim to reduce battery usage, improve memory management or speed, are all bunk and have no real effect or make the problem worse. Undo any changed the app made and remove it. If you want real improvement, use a custom ROM and/or kernel.

Comment: @acejavelin what makes you say that?

Comment: seriously? Google it, every respected Android source will reinforce what I said. Android Central, XDA, Android Authority, Android Police, etc

Comment: @acejavelin just because many are crappy doesn't mean they all are. That's like saying since many free antivirus are actually viruses, you shouldn't use an antivirus.